# HTTP trigger Cloud Function in Flutter web

Tags: python, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a `HTTP trigger Cloud Function` from `Flutter`. I keep getting errors in the console while passing the parameters to the function. [image: Cloud Function]

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
 functionName: 'hello_world',
);

final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
  <String, dynamic>{
    'message': 'hello world!',
  },
);
```

Can someone point out what is it that I am doing wrong. The `Cloud function` used is

```
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your Cloud Function please?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the `Cloud Function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from your screenshot of the Google Cloud Console that your HTTP Cloud Function is written in Python.

On the other hand, in your Dart code, you are calling a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

At the time of writing, Callable Cloud Functions are only supported on Cloud Functions by using the Firebase SDK for Node.js.

If you want an HTTP Cloud Function written in Python to work with your Dart code you will need to implement the [protocol for `https.onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) in the Cloud Function itself.

You'll find an example [here](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/create-compatitle-cloud-function-for-firebase-with-python/) (untested).

---

**Update following your comment above:** From you Cloud Function code, we can confirm that you don't implement the protocol for `https.onCall`.

Comment: I created a new `Cloud Function` in `Node.js 8`. Only changed the function name. I am still getting the errors. `Uncaught TypeError:a.functions is not a function`. Are these `Callable Cloud Functions` compatible with all the currently available `Node.js` versions?

Comment: The supported Node.js versions are Node.js 8 and Node.js 10 (Beta). How are you creating and deploying your functions? Through the Firebase CLI?

Comment: No, I creating the functions from Google cloud and I used Node.js 8.

Comment: This is the problem I think. As said above, you need to use the Firebase SDK for Node.js

Comment: Thank you, @Renaud...Let me try the `https.onCall` as well. Since the `Cloud Functions` that I have written are in `python`.