# How can I use a Python Cloud Function in flutter using HTTP triggers?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created a cloud function on Google Cloud Platform using Python 3.7. Now I want to call this function to my Flutter app using an HTTP trigger. I cannot use the cloud_functions package since the Callable Cloud Functions SDK for Firebase is only configured for Typescript or NodeJS functions as of now (according to this answer: [HTTP trigger Cloud Function in Flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203117/http-trigger-cloud-function-in-flutter-web)). So how do I go about using a Google Cloud Function?

My use case involves taking a user String input, then based on the cloud function, return the desired output for that input in the form of a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an HTTP request to the Cloud Functions endpoint, see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data